# How can we construct a degree $k$ cover of $\mathbb P^1$ by a curve of genus $g$ with $b$ branch points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I read in a paper that it is a consequence of the Riemann-Roch Theorem that given a projective non-singular curve $V$ of genus $g$ (defined over the complex numbers, say), and numbers $k,b$ such that $k>g+1$ there exists a degree $k$ cover of $\mathbb P^1$ by $V$ with $b$ branch points.

I tried to prove this myself but can't fill in all the details.

**My attempted proof:**

> First consider the unbranched case.  Let $P_1,\dots,P_k$ be distinct points on $V$.  Let $D=P_1+\dots P_k$.  Then Riemann's Theorem tells us that
>
> $$
> l(D)\ge1-g+\deg(D)=1-g+k>0
> $$
>
> so there exists a rational function $f$ on $V$ with zeroes at the points $P_1,\dots,P_k$.  Then the morphism $\phi\colon V\to\mathbb P^1$ given by $\phi=(1:f)$ has fibre over $(1:0)$ of cardinality $k$.

At this point, I'd like to claim that $\phi$ is the desired degree $k$ cover.  But I don't know how to show that $\phi$ isn't of some higher degree and just ramified over $(1:0)$.  Also, I'd prefer to be able to come up with some slick way to show that the fibre over a general point in $\mathbb P^1$ has cardinality $k$, rather than by appealing to the general picture of a morphism into $\mathbb P^1$ as being an $n$-fold cover, ramified at finitely many points.

For the branched case, I suppose you use some different degree $k$ divisor $D$ and proceed as before.  But I'm confused about the relationship between ramification of the morphism $\phi=(1:f)$ and the zeroes/poles of the rational function $f$.

Comment: What you claim you read is not correct: once $g$ and $k$ are given, you can't choose $b$, which necessarily satisfies $b=2g-2+2k$ by Hurwitz's theorem.